# Subtracting dates of UK format in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have this query:

```
select received, eventdatetime, STR_TO_DATE(eventdatetime,'%d/%m/%Y') - 
STR_TO_DATE(received,'%d/%m/%Y'), status from scdr;
```

Which returns the below:

[image: Query result]

However, you can see that eg, the difference of 72 'days' isn't correct here.

Is this a UK / US date issue, or something else? should the function not resolve are internationalization issues?

Comment: there is no 71 value in image there 72 and 73

Comment: why are you storing your dates as strings? The format is just a presentational style for human viewing, not a means of storing the data. Store them in proper date columns and any problem relating to formatted strings goes away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use datediff funtion

```
    select received, eventdatetime,
    datediff(STR_TO_DATE(received,'%d/%m/%Y'),STR_TO_DATE(eventdatetime,'%d/%m/%Y')) status from scdr;
```

Comment: @autosermo does it helps?